# React with node JS API - Facebook auth

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs

I'm new on node JS, I was working on ruby and RoR and I've decided to learn new langage : Javascript with nodeJS and React/Redux. I have an app and I want to create an authentication system using Facebook auth.

I find this on a topic :
[image]

(link : https://medium.com/@robince885/node-js-rest-api-facebook-login-121114ee04d8)

So I find this pretty clear, but the topic use Angular client, and I want to use React/Redux for the front part. 
To sum up, I want to create an API using NodeJS / Express, and a client using React/Redux.

First, I can't find any package or library for facebook-auth with react, like sattelize for angular,

And does someone have a good tutorial to implement this auth with Node JS ?

Thank !

Comment: You should definitely check this out https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov I have already check this library and test it, but what to do with it ? I retrieve access_token, id, name, picture, ok fine, but is this safe to get these data from front and send them to my DB with my API ? Is this more safe to just get a code and create the user retrieve logic with API ?

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to comment but couldn't as less reputation but did you try https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth

It is based from 'devise' gem of ruby on rails

As far as I understand with an OAuth flow you would need client/browser interaction at-least for the first consent